# Is there any technical difference between these methods?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to learn OO JS. I was playing with different patterns, wrote following example.

```
var obj = function() {

    this.a= function() {
        return 'a';
    } 
}

obj.prototype.b = function() {
    return 'b';
} 


var instance = new obj();

console.log(instance.a());
console.log(instance.b());
```

Is there any difference here in function a and b?

Comment: `(new obj).a !== (new obj).a` while `(new obj).b === (new obj).b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.a` will be a separate function for every object you create:

```
var obj = function() {    
    this.a= function() {
        return 'a';
    } 
}

obj.prototype.b = function() {
    return 'b';
} 

var instance1 = new obj();
var instance2 = new obj();

console.log(instance1 === instance2);     // false: different instances
console.log(instance1.a === instance2.a); // false: different functions (this.a)
console.log(instance1.b === instance2.b); // true:  obj.prototype.b
```

This means that `this.a = function(){ ... }` will consume memory for every instance, something you most likely want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `a` is a function of the *instance*, whereas `b` is a function of the *class*.

In terms of them actually working, there isn't much different between them by themselves. However, let's say you put `var test = 123;` inside the `obj` function. `a` will be able to access it, but `b` will not.

Additionally, you can overwrite `instance.a` with another function, and it will only affect the current instance.

On the other hand, `a` is a separate function object for each instance of the object. This could become a problem in terms of memory use if you have large numbers of instances.

Comment: even if this explanation is somewhat correct, there are no classes in javascript.

Comment: Just close as a dupe instead of giving imperfect answers :-)